# Change from ArrayList<String[]> to String[][] in java

Tags: java, arraylist

What's the easiest way to change `ArrayList<String[]>` to `String[][]/Object[][]` table?

I tried to use `size()` method, but this type of list doesn't have simple method `get()`.

Thanks for help.

```
_rowTable[j][0] = new String[_listSelect.size()][columnCount];

for(int j=0; j < _listSelect.size(); j++)
 //   for(int k=0; k < columnCount; k++)
        _rowTable[j][0] = _listSelect.get(0);
```

How to use second loop inside properly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use `List.toArray(T[])`

```
List<String[]> listOfStringArray = ...
String[][] arrayOfStringArray = listOfStringArray.toArray(
                                        new String[listOfStringArray.size()][]);
```

Comment: Cast to String[][] is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
...
Object[][] objectArray = list.toArray(new Object[list.size()][]);
String[][] stringArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()][]);
```